# Printing to a thermal printer from an mvc web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, printing

Myself and team are currently in the planning stages of a re-write of a legacy visual basic 6 application. There are a few aspects of this application that don't seem to fit well with a web app as output is at times directly pushed to a thermal printer.

We were thinking of building a small standalone console application that simply listened to a print queue to handle this output.

Does this sound feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF for client-side printing seems to be WTG: [Printing receipt ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705379/printing-receipt-asp-net)

Otherwise if this is an internally accessed web app you may be able to use the thermal printer in server-side code - or from server-side code call a console app to queue print jobs.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, the majority of the client side printing we need to do will be handled with crystal reports. The issue of concern for us was the server-side printing to these printers. But I think were on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

We actually just implemented a solution similar to this in our own MVC application. We render what we need to print to a PDF and we print the PDF using the Foxit command line.